# isotope not working with appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml-parsing, jquery-isotope

I have a problem where I am not able to filter my data that is parsed from a local .xml file. I have some demo images in the same container which is working and filtering. So isotope.js is indeed setup properly. Could you possibly see what is wrong?

Here is my setup.

index.html(Html + bootstrap)
`

```
<a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".people">People</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".places">Places</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".food">Food</a>
<a href="#" data-filter=".objects">Objects</a>
```

```
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 skolLista portfolioContainer">`
```

javascript.js

`

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert, console*/
 $(window).on('load', function () {

     var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });

    $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         return false;
    }); 

 });



 $(document).ready(function(){
             $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "skolor.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser

            });
        });

        function xmlParser(xml){

            $(xml).find("Skola").each(function(){
            var namn = $(this).find('Namn').text(); 
            var adress = $(this).find('Adress').text();
            var arskurser = $(this).find('Arskurser').text();  
            var huvudman = $(this).find('Regi').text();  
            var antalElever = $(this).find('Antal_elever').text(); 
            var andelBehorigaLarae = $(this).find('Andel_behoriga_larare').text();
            var skolansEpost = $(this).find('').text();
                var skolanstelefon = $(this).find('Telefon').text();
               /* var skolansEpost = $(this).find('').text();*/


            $(".portfolioContainer").append("<div class='element people ' > <h3 class='grid-item people'>" + namn + "</h3>" + 
                    "<p class='grid-item arskurser food'>" + arskurser + "</p>" + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Jämför</button> <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">' + "<p class='grid-item antalElever'> Antal elever:" + antalElever + "</p>" +  "<p class='grid-item huvudman'> Regi:" + huvudman + "</p>" + "<p class='grid-item'> Andel Behöriga Lärare:" + andelBehorigaLarae + "</p>" + "</div>" );  



            });


        } 

    `
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with

```
  var $items = $(html);

  //Add item to isotope
  $('.grid').isotope( 'insert', $items );
```